# Default Ripple Effect disapears when using Selector

Tags: android, listview, selector, ripple

I have a ListView which hast by DEFAULT the normal android ripple effect.When I touch an element it is showing the animation. I didn't add anything in my xml code for this.

But now I want to use a selector for my parent Layout because I want to highlight it when I select it in my contextual action bar. And surprisingly the Ripple effect is gone ...

My XML for Selector is simple as that :

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item android:state_activated="true" android:drawable="@color/listview_highlight"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/listview_normal" />

</selector>
```

I found out that you can use

> "< ripple >< /ripple > "

But that needs an Api min 21.

I want to set the animation to default like it was in the past.

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found a solution by doing try / error.
I just needed to add

> android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"

To my ListView and Voilaa !
Everything is working fine now , hopefully this post can help someone !

Comment: that was helpful, but I have the solid color so the background view is not appearing when keeping that as true. So I managed that from code level... 
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            listview.setDrawSelectorOnTop(true);
        }.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create two selectors:

Keep your current selector in the `values` folder and add copy the file to `values-v21`.
Then you can add `<ripple></ripple>` in `values-v21`.

Comment: But then the users under API lvl 21 wont get any click effect.Not even the normal android standard click effect , dont they ? Because the click effect is completely gone when I use this Selector